# Работа с SVG через object

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, svg

Ребят, такая ситуация, вставляю svg через object, но стили не задаются (имею ввиду заливку - fill), вот код html:

```
<object data="img/Icon/interface.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="icon"></object>
```

Вот код картинки:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 253 248"> <path  d="M227.699 1.199H25.301c-13.234 0-24 10.766-24 24v197.602c0 13.23 10.766 24 24 24h202.398c13.235 0 24-10.77 24-24V25.199c0-13.234-10.765-24-24-24zm0 24l.008 104.98-40.543-38.078c-2.836-2.66-6.468-4.125-10.226-4.125-4.571 0-8.848 2.145-11.739 5.883l-47.73 61.805c-1.547 2.004-4.027 3.199-6.637 3.199-1.781 0-3.461-.539-4.863-1.566l-31.016-22.653c-3.09-2.254-7.093-3.5-11.269-3.5-4.758 0-9.203 1.551-12.52 4.367l-25.863 21.934V25.199h202.398zm0 0"/><path d="M93.301 96.398c13.676 0 24.801-11.125 24.801-24.801 0-13.671-11.125-24.796-24.801-24.796-13.676 0-24.801 11.125-24.801 24.796 0 13.676 11.125 24.801 24.801 24.801zm0 0"/></svg>
```

Что делаю не так? подскажите, пожалуйста, оптимальный способ стилизации

Comment: а как выставляете `fill` ? может быть [эта статья](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#article-header-id-11) поможет?

Comment: Ну так, это способ с точки зрения контроля над svg мало чем отличется от тега img. Внутрь svg вы из документа (или стилей документа) не достучитесь.

Comment: получается лучше всего линейно вставлять и не парить мозг ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы управлять цветом заливки и другими атрибутами в файле SVG нужно выполнить несколько действий:

1. Удалить ***fill, stroke*** из файла svg. У вас их нет.
2. fill в svg не наследует родительские свойства, поэтому необходимо

добавить  для - ***path{fill: inherit;}***

3.В svg файл добавить строку с указанием управляющего внешнего файла CSS

```
***<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="css/svg.css" ?>***
```

Пример кода ниже. Добавил изменение цвета иконки при наведении курсора.

```css
#journey{ 
fill:orange;
}
#journey:hover{ 
fill:crimson;
}
path{
fill:inherit;
stroke:inherit;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="svg.css" ?>
<svg version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
  width="800" height="800" viewBox="0 0 800 800" > 
 
 <path id="journey"    d="M227.699 1.199H25.301c-13.234 0-24 10.766-24 24v197.602c0 13.23 10.766 24 24 24h202.398c13.235 0 24-10.77 24-24V25.199c0-13.234-10.765-24-24-24zm0 24l.008 104.98-40.543-38.078c-2.836-2.66-6.468-4.125-10.226-4.125-4.571 0-8.848 2.145-11.739 5.883l-47.73 61.805c-1.547 2.004-4.027 3.199-6.637 3.199-1.781 0-3.461-.539-4.863-1.566l-31.016-22.653c-3.09-2.254-7.093-3.5-11.269-3.5-4.758 0-9.203 1.551-12.52 4.367l-25.863 21.934V25.199h202.398zm0 0M93.301 96.398c13.676 0 24.801-11.125 24.801-24.801 0-13.671-11.125-24.796-24.801-24.796-13.676 0-24.801 11.125-24.801 24.796 0 13.676 11.125 24.801 24.801 24.801zm0 0"/>
 </svg>
```

Всё точно так же работает, когда вставляете SVG файл, через `<object>`
к сожалению не могу показать, так как не могу подключить внешний файл `data="icon.svg"`

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
  <object type="image/svg+xml" data="icon.svg" width="400" height="400"> </object>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```