# Как поменять цвет у SVG вставленную через object

Tags: css, svg

Не могу поменять цвет у SVG вставленную черех object. Вот так на странице вставляю SVG. Где $blockElement путь до SVG.

```
<object
   type="image/svg+xml"
   data="<?=$blockElement['icon']?>">
</object>
```

Код SVG

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 20.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0) --><svg version="1.0" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve"><style type="text/css">.st0{fill:#3D9D58;}</style><g><g><path class="st0" d="M488.5,188.4H373.6L292.9,32.7c-2.9-5.6-7.8-9.7-13.8-11.6c-6-1.9-12.4-1.4-17.9,1.5c-1.9,1-3.7,2.3-5.2,3.7c-1.5-1.4-3.3-2.7-5.2-3.7c-5.6-2.9-12-3.4-17.9-1.5c-6,1.9-10.9,6-13.8,11.6L134,196.8c-2.9,5.6-3.4,12-1.5,17.9c0.6,2,1.6,4,2.7,5.7H23.5c-4.7,0-8.5-3.8-8.5-8.5c0-4.7,3.8-8.5,8.5-8.5H109c4.1,0,7.5-3.4,7.5-7.5c0-4.1-3.4-7.5-7.5-7.5H23.5c-13,0-23.5,10.6-23.5,23.5c0,10.8,7.3,19.9,17.1,22.6l43.4,231.7c2.8,14.9,15.8,25.7,31,25.7h328.8c15.2,0,28.2-10.8,31-25.7l43.4-231.7c9.9-2.8,17.1-11.9,17.1-22.6C512,198.9,501.4,188.4,488.5,188.4z M268.1,36c2-1,4.3-1.2,6.5-0.6c2.2,0.7,3.9,2.2,5,4.2l85.1,164.1c1,2,1.2,4.3,0.6,6.5c-0.7,2.2-2.2,3.9-4.2,5c-2,1.1-4.3,1.2-6.5,0.6s-3.9-2.2-5-4.2L264.5,47.5C262.3,43.3,263.9,38.2,268.1,36z M368,235.4l-7.1,73.2h-97.4v-73.2H368z M256,63.8l80.2,154.7c0.4,0.7,0.7,1.3,1.2,2H174.6c0.4-0.6,0.8-1.3,1.2-2l7.8-15.1h114.2c4.1,0,7.5-3.4,7.5-7.5c0-4.1-3.4-7.5-7.5-7.5H191.4L256,63.8z M147.3,203.7l85.1-164.1c1-2,2.8-3.5,5-4.2c0.9-0.3,1.7-0.4,2.6-0.4c1.3,0,2.7,0.3,3.9,1c4.2,2.2,5.8,7.3,3.6,11.5l-85.1,164.1c-1,2-2.8,3.5-5,4.2c-2.2,0.7-4.5,0.5-6.5-0.6c-2-1-3.5-2.8-4.2-5C146.1,208,146.3,205.7,147.3,203.7z M32.6,235.4H129l7.1,73.2H46.3L32.6,235.4z M49.1,323.6h88.4l7.1,73.2H62.8L49.1,323.6z M91.6,477c-8,0-14.8-5.7-16.3-13.5l-9.7-51.7h80.4l6.3,65.2L91.6,477L91.6,477z M248.5,477h-81.1l-6.3-65.2h87.4V477z M248.5,396.8h-88.8l-7.1-73.2h95.9V396.8z M248.5,308.6h-97.4l-7.1-73.2h104.5V308.6z M344.6,477h-81.1v-65.2h87.4L344.6,477z M352.3,396.8h-88.8v-73.2h95.9L352.3,396.8z M436.7,463.5c-1.5,7.8-8.3,13.5-16.3,13.5h-60.8l6.3-65.2h80.4L436.7,463.5z M449.2,396.8h-81.8l7.1-73.2h88.4L449.2,396.8z M465.7,308.6H376l7.1-73.2h96.4L465.7,308.6z M488.5,220.4h-0.1c0,0,0,0,0,0H376.8c1.1-1.8,2.1-3.7,2.7-5.7c1.2-3.7,1.4-7.6,0.7-11.4h108.2c4.7,0,8.5,3.8,8.5,8.5S493.2,220.4,488.5,220.4z"/></g></g></svg>
```

Вот этот [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526539/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-svg-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-object) порбывал  не поехало.
P.S Вставить SVG инлайного не предоставляется возможности. Прошу помощи

Comment: а к самому svg есть доступ ?

Comment: @Goryyn , подобные одноцветные векторные иконки удобнее всего добавлять на сайт иконочным шрифтом. При этом остаётся возможность оперировать цветом и размером через `css`. "Font-awesome" видели? Такой же шрифт из СВОИХ иконок можно создать при помощи сервиса   https://icomoon.io/app/

Answer (score 0):

Чтоб было  управление SVG.  Сделал так - 
Вставил на страницу SVG черех img . так как svg грузится на странциу отдельным документом.  Просто забрал его аяксом  и заменил  на странице